# TinyMCE browser "fixes"

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, tinymce, opera

I'm getting a javascript error in Firefox and Opera when I'm using TinyMCE:

```
j is null
(function(d){var a=/^\s*|\s*$/g,e,c="B...a.selection.onSetContent.add(f)})}});
```

This error comes up after I save the contents of the textarea for the 2nd time, 3rd etc. First time it gets saved...

Since it's working fine in the other browsers (IE and Chrome), I assume the issue is within the "TinyMCE" fixes which Opera and probably Firefox too are running...

Is there any way I can stop these browsers from applying these fixes? Anyway it seems ridiculous to me for a browser to attempt to fix a 3rd party script

Comment: Firefox doesn't run any TinyMCE-specific fixes.

Comment: Hi Alex, I've personally written every TinyMCE "fix" Opera applies. If you have any less "ridiculous" ways to solve these compat problems I'd love to hear them :-)

Comment: Well don't get my wrong I looove Opera, but why would such a great browser attempt to fix a buggy js app like TinyMCE? :/

Comment: @Alex, because people who use TinyMCE want it to work in Opera? Why do you assume that the Opera-applied fixes are the problem? Did you disable Browser JS and test for yourself to come to that conclusion? Type "opera:config", and search for "Browser JavaScript". Set it to "0" to disable Browser JS. Try testing again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a tinymce bug. Internally, the tinymce code uses a `<span id="mce_marker"></span>` to remember the caret-position when pasting. when validating the resulting fragment, after the paste, the span is deemed invalid and removed, thus breaking the code by removing the marker.
This issue will be fixed in the next official tinymce minor release. There are some workarounds for this kind of issue. One is to add `id` and `mce-data-type` attribute to `spans` [as valid elements (init setting)](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements). Example:

```
// The valid_elements option defines which elements will remain in the edited text when the editor saves.
    valid_elements: "@[id|class|title|style]," +
    "a[name|href|target|title]," +
    "#p,-ol,-ul,-li,br,img[src],-sub,-sup,-b,-i,-u," +
    "-span[data-mce-type]",
```